# Add Header taken from query parameter

Tags: haproxy

In my application to like to do a navigate to a link. Unfortunately, I am not able to add an access token to the Authorization header.

For this reason, I like to add it as a query parameter. When the request is processed in HAProxy I like to retrieve query parameter and add an Authorization header using the parameter value.

I would be very happy if someone has an idea why it is not working;

The following configuration I have added to HAProxy configuration. We testing I notice that the header is added, as it overwrites the Authorization when I add a header for test purpose.

Thanks,

Andreas

```
http-request set-var(req.token) urlp(token)
http-request set-header Authorization var(req.token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `%[...]` around your set-header fmt expression, namely:

```
http-request set-var(req.token) urlp(token)
http-request set-header Authorization %[var(req.token)]
```